# pass object variable to ' form.is_valid(): ' function in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm working on a bulk update functionality in django. I have a table that shows the data in my database, and the user selects the objects they would like to edit. Once selected, they click a "Bulk Update" button and it takes them to a django ModelForm.  The partial view for this page is such :

```
def BulkUpdate(request):
  c = {}
  c.update(csrf(request))
  if request.method == "POST":
    pks = request.POST.getlist("selection")
    selected_objects = mymodel.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
    form = BulkUpdateForm(request.POST)
    print (selected_objects)
    if form.is_valid():
        gender = form.data['gender']
        print (gender)
        print (selected_objects)
    return render(request, 'bulkUpdate.html', {'form': form })
```

The first `print (selected_objects)` successfully prints all objects that were selected from the prior template within on QuerySet.  However the second `print (selected_objects)` returns a blank QuerySet.  For example, if three objects are selected my terminal will print

`<QuerySet [<model: model object>, <model: model object>, <model: model object>]>`

but upon submitting a valid form it will print

`<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet []>`

Two because I'm printing it twice in my code..

My main question is how can I get those three objects into my form.is_valid() function. I'd like for my variable `selected_objects` to be printed the same way in both calls.  Any help or advice is amazing. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It just can't be like that. You print the same queryset twice and result will be the same. I would bet that `form.is_valid()` is False and you have 2 more prints somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. I wish it was. I know that the function is being called because my input for gender is returned. I think it's that when I initially hit the bulk update button to take me to the form page, it grabs the objects, but when I submit the form it no longer has access to the objects that were selected? It just returns an empty queryset.  I was thinking of maybe using a token? but I don't have much token experience and I'm not sure if that's even a safe way of handling it.

Comment: What is the value of `print(pks)`? If it is an empty list, then you are not including `selection` in the POST data when you submit the form.

Comment: As an aside, you can remove `c = {}` and `c.update(csrf(request))` from your code. You don't need to include the csrf token manually when you use the `render` shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for your response and the tip about removing that snippet.  For pks, it's a similar situation. When I initially click "Bulk Update" to take me to the form, it prints a list containing the pks of the selected objects. When I submit the valid form, pks prints an empty list.  How would you suggest I include `selection` in the POST data when I submit the form?

Comment: I've tried editing my form variable to `form = BulkUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=selected_objects)` but I'll get a `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'` error which technically makes sense but I don't know a way around it.

Comment: If you want to pass multiple objects to a form, it should be a `FormSet` not a `ModelForm` or `Form`. Try to convert your `QuerySet` to `list()` first, maybe it's empty the second time because its iterator reaches the end of it, so you dont see anything in there then.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I need to find a way to put the `pks` variable into the url then I can access the pk's through that when I submit my form.  I'll post an answer once I get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def BulkUpdate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pks = request.POST.getlist("selection")
        form = BulkUpdateForm(request.POST)
        pk_string = "/".join(str(i) for i in pk_list)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = request.path
            pk_mod=url[33:].split('/')
            objects = mymodel.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_mod)
            gender = form.data['gender']
            for i in objects:
                i.gender = gender
                i.save()
                print('done')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(pk_string)
    else:
        form = BulkUpdateForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'bulkUpdate.html', {'form':form })
```

I successfully used this method to get the pk's of the objects selected, take it to a form template while saving the pk's in the url, then using the url to strip the pk's and filter my objects using the method I used previously. From there, any input that gets put into `gender` in my `BulkUpdateForm()` will replace the gender field for all of the selected objects.  Thank you for everyone's help, hopefully my snippet can help someone out later on.